# JavaScript download path

Tags: javascript, download, path, mp3

I've got a external YouTube download link in which I put a link and then it downloads but I wish to set a path to where the download goes. How can I do this?

It puts it in the download folder by default but I wish to put it in Downloads/MyApp/music for example.

How can I accomplish this?

With kind regards

Comment: This question [has been answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915688/set-download-path). I hope this helps!

Comment: I cant quite figure out how to let it work. I've used *file_put_contents* in PHP before but is there something for JavaScript with the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

Download path is set in the user's preference in the browser which cannot be bypass. Also js does not have access to local file system & that will give rise to a big security concern