# Download to a particular folder from a web application

Tags: javascript, java, html, google-chrome

I have a web application, I have a requirement to download more than 10 files to a folder. By default the download happens to browser download location. The user have a new requirement to have an option to select the folder where there need to save the file from web application. Could you please let me know whether it is possible in all browsers, I know by default chrome starts downloading to download folder. The user will be searching with some condition and all files which match the condition should be downloaded to the folder given by user.

Could you please let me know whether I can override the download location in browser like chrome.

Comment: check out this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915688/set-download-path - should be answering your question?