# use javascript or dojo to download .png from a remote server to a local directory other than download folder

Tags: javascript, dojo

I know the url of pngs from a remote server, for instance http://ww.imagewebsite.com/texas/houston/images/city.png. How to save a copy of pngs to a local directory other than download folder using javascript or dojo?

Comment: What de you mean by dwnload folder ?

Comment: i mean the Windows default Download folder.

Comment: [This SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3915688/set-download-path?rq=1) may answer your question.