# How to save image of div to gallery of mobile device?

Tags: javascript, instagram, android-gallery, webpage-screenshot

I'm working on a small web based app.
[www.wrootle.com](http://www.wrootle.com)
You can type text to a box. I use it to make quotes for instagram. So i type text in the box, make a screenshot which gets saved to my gallery and then upload from there when i make a post. Is there a javascript way to save an image of the textarea to the gallery of my mobile device?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [download attribute](https://www.w3schools.com/TAgs/att_a_download.asp) to achive this. Example:

```html
<a href="https://m.popkey.co/987552/NGLb3.gif" download><img src="https://m.popkey.co/987552/NGLb3.gif"></a>
```

Comment: Can i tell it to download to gallery?

Comment: No, that is configured by the browser/user. I have tested it on my mobile and it downloaded into my downloads directory.

Comment: Take a look of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3915705/4637140): `JavaScript cannot exert any control over my (the visitor's) local filesystem`

Comment: Unfortunate. How else could i get an image of the textarea to the mobile device gallery?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood your original question. You have to use a canvas element to join the image and the textarea text

Comment: Ok, but still I can't save it to the mobile device gallery?

Comment: Only to the download folder or the path that the user has set